# Why would a significant non-zero angle of attack be an advantage during 1st stage burn?

Tags: launch, aerodynamics, flightclub

From videos of both the SES-10 launch shown in @RussellBorogove's question, [Cause of apparent plume deflection on SES-10?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20916/12102) and the Block 5 launch  [Bangabandhu Satellite-1 Mission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQEqKZ7CJlk) at `T+ 01:48` it appears the Falcon 9 uses non-zero angles of attack (or [displacement angle](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17184/12102)) during the 1st stage burn.

The exhaust plume is aligned with the flight path (high dynamic pressure) and it's obvious the vehicle's roll axis isn't.

The [accepted answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20944/12102) states:

> I believe the visual effect is due to the rocket flying a small positive angle of attack at the end of the first stage burn, combined with a steeply foreshortened camera view.
>
> According to the simulation data at FlightClub (https://www.flightclub.io/results/?code=SS10), the rocket flies a positive angle-of-attack during the end of the first stage burn, peaking at about 4.6 degrees AoA.

Is this advantageous?

[image] [image]

**left:** screen shot from Bangabandhu video, **right:** SES-10 from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20916/12102). Click for larger size.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot? See for example these questions  [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20916/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6336/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22305/12102), [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18159/12102)

Comment: Would do it if I knew how. As I mentioned a few days ago, I've been doing professional space exploration for a long time, but I'm new to online stuff. Still on the learning curve.

Comment: Can see the result of what you did (time tag icon, screen shot inserted) but not how you did it.

Comment: I did everything using the keyboard except for importing the screenshot. To import images, you use the "image" tool at the top of the edit window. See this guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcK5Q.png To get a short link to a question or an answer, look for and click `share` below the post. It pops open a small window. You just use your keyboard shortcut for copy and then it's in your copy/paste buffer. See this guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuUF0.png

Comment: slightly related: [Is aerodynamic lift ever useful in rocket flight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17093/12102)

Comment: I've added several items to the question to give examples of how these things work. You can of course remove some if it looks too busy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to fly an ascent trajectory with zero angle of attack throughout -- this would be an ideal gravity turn.  In practice, launches have a fairly specific main engine cut off (MECO) state vector that they are guided to however.  This requires some angle of attack, usually commanded via gimbaling and limited by q-alpha, to alter the trajectory.

Comment: I see. This tells me that the control methodology is that there is a defined ascent trajectory (and thus a defined state vector at MECO) that the vehicle is trying to match. If at any time the actual position of the vehicle deviates from that trajectory (say, from unanticipated upper-level winds), the vehicle begins canceling the deviation via a non-zero AoA. This is the methodology the Saturn V used. An alternative methodology, one that requires smaller AoA's, is to calculate, on-the-fly, "What is the best trajectory to my desired end state *from where I am now*?", and fly that.

Comment: Pretty much.  There are all kinds of first stage guidance techniques -- open loop, closed loop, etc.  I believe Falcon 9 has closed loop first stage guidance however, so your summary is accurate.  Sometimes, first stage guidance will also do trajectory shaping for aborts and to avoid downrange regions -- all of which will require angle of attack changes.  I am sure F9 does all of these things.  Cheers.

Comment: Most/all of the answers to [Is aerodynamic lift ever useful in rocket flight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17093/12102) state that deviations from non-zero AoA are *quite undesirable and minimized*, especially for this long, skinny [flying noodle](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21669/12102). But it sounds like as long as the altitude is sufficient, q-alpha can be kept in check.